# How to update scope after initial submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to Angular so I feel I'm missing something basic here. I have a simple app with 5 screens. on the first three screens users enter in numbers that get calculated on the last two screens as a sumarry. I have my forms setup to submit the data and make an api call to Zillow on submit. My problem is that if I go back to the screen after leaving and submitting the data, I can't get the data to update on the summary screens. I think it's a scope issue but I'm at a loss for how to handle it.

So in short, when I change data in the form fields and click submit for a second time, nothing gets updated on the summary pages.

Here's what I have in my controller.

```
 angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('PropCtrl', function($scope, zillowFactory, $rootScope) {
  // pass data from form fields to zillowFactory
  // store returned object for use in view
  // $scope.update = fucntion() {};
  // make api call to Zillow
  // pass back object from zillow
  $scope.prop = zillowFactory.prop;

  $scope.update = function(){
    console.log('update ran')
    zillowFactory.getProperty($scope.prop);
  };
})

.controller('IncomeCtrl',['$scope','zillowFactory', function($scope, zillowFactory) {
  $scope.prop = zillowFactory.prop;

  $scope.update = function(){
    zillowFactory.getProperty($scope.prop);
  };

  var rentalincome = ($scope.prop.rental || 0);
  var house = ($scope.prop.householdincome || 0);
  $scope.prop.totalincome = (house * 1)+ rentalincome;

}])
.controller('ExpensesCtrl',['$scope','zillowFactory', function($scope, zillowFactory) {
  $scope.prop = zillowFactory.prop;
  $scope.update = function(){
    zillowFactory.getProperty();
  };

}])

.controller('SumCtrl', ['$scope', 'zillowFactory', function($scope, zillowFactory) {
  $scope.prop = zillowFactory.prop;

  zillowFactory.getProperty();
   var expenses30 = ($scope.prop.monthlypayment.response.monthlyPropertyTaxes * 12) + ($scope.prop.monthlypayment.response.monthlyHazardInsurance * 12) + ($scope.prop.monthlypayment.response.thirtyYearFixed.monthlyPrincipalAndInterest * 12) + ($scope.prop.maintenance * 12)
   + ($scope.prop.fees * 12) + ($scope.prop.utilities * 12) + ($scope.prop.other * 12) + ($scope.prop.price/27.5);

   var expensesfifteen = ($scope.prop.monthlypayment.response.monthlyPropertyTaxes * 12) + ($scope.prop.monthlypayment.response.monthlyHazardInsurance * 12) + ($scope.prop.monthlypayment.response.fifteenYearFixed.monthlyPrincipalAndInterest * 12) + ($scope.prop.maintenance * 12)
   + ($scope.prop.fees * 12) + ($scope.prop.utilities * 12) + ($scope.prop.other * 12) + ($scope.prop.price/27.5);


   var expensesfive = ($scope.prop.monthlypayment.response.monthlyPropertyTaxes * 12) + ($scope.prop.monthlypayment.response.monthlyHazardInsurance * 12) + ($scope.prop.monthlypayment.response.fiveOneARM.monthlyPrincipalAndInterest * 12) + ($scope.prop.maintenance * 12)
   + ($scope.prop.fees * 12) + ($scope.prop.utilities * 12) + ($scope.prop.other * 12) + ($scope.prop.price/27.5);

   $scope.prop.expenses30 = expenses30;
   $scope.prop.expenses15 = expensesfifteen;
   $scope.prop.expenses5 =  expensesfive;

}])
.controller('AnalysisCtrl', [ '$scope', 'zillowFactory', '$location', '$window', function($scope, zillowFactory, $location, $window) {
$scope.prop = zillowFactory.setProperty($scope.prop);

   zillowFactory.getProperty($scope.prop);

   var taxerate = 4/10;

   var annualincome = $scope.prop.householdincome + ($scope.prop.rental * 12);
   $scope.annualincome = annualincome;

   var expenses30 = ($scope.prop.monthlypayment.response.monthlyPropertyTaxes * 12) + ($scope.prop.monthlypayment.response.monthlyHazardInsurance * 12) + ($scope.prop.monthlypayment.response.thirtyYearFixed.monthlyPrincipalAndInterest * 12) + ($scope.prop.maintenance * 12)
   + ($scope.prop.fees * 12) + ($scope.prop.utilities * 12) + ($scope.prop.other * 12) + ($scope.prop.price/27.5);

   var expensesfifteen = ($scope.prop.monthlypayment.response.monthlyPropertyTaxes * 12) + ($scope.prop.monthlypayment.response.monthlyHazardInsurance * 12) + ($scope.prop.monthlypayment.response.fifteenYearFixed.monthlyPrincipalAndInterest * 12) + ($scope.prop.maintenance * 12)
   + ($scope.prop.fees * 12) + ($scope.prop.utilities * 12) + ($scope.prop.other * 12) + ($scope.prop.price/27.5);


   var expensesfive = ($scope.prop.monthlypayment.response.monthlyPropertyTaxes * 12) + ($scope.prop.monthlypayment.response.monthlyHazardInsurance * 12) + ($scope.prop.monthlypayment.response.fiveOneARM.monthlyPrincipalAndInterest * 12) + ($scope.prop.maintenance * 12)
   + ($scope.prop.fees * 12) + ($scope.prop.utilities * 12) + ($scope.prop.other * 12) + ($scope.prop.price/27.5);

   $scope.prop.expenses30 = expenses30;
   $scope.prop.expenses15 = expensesfifteen;
   $scope.prop.expenses5 =  expensesfive;

  var adjusted = annualincome - expenses30;

  var taxes = adjusted * taxerate;



  var adjustedfifteen = annualincome - expensesfifteen;

  var taxes15 = adjustedfifteen * taxerate;

  var adjusted5 = annualincome - expensesfive;

  var taxes5 = adjusted5 * taxerate;

  $scope.maxwriteoff30 = 250000;

  $scope.prop.cashflow30rep = annualincome - taxes;
  $scope.prop.cashflow15rep = annualincome - taxes15;
  $scope.prop.cashflow5rep = annualincome - taxes5;

  var adjustedWOrep = annualincome - 25000;
  var taxesWOrep = adjustedWOrep * taxerate;

  $scope.cashflowWOrep = adjustedWOrep - taxesWOrep;


   $scope.refresh = function() {

          $location.path('/tab/prop');
          $window.location.reload();

   };

}]);
```

Here's how all of my form views are set up.
Prop.html

```
      <form novalidate>

      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">Purchase Price</span>
        <input name="prop[price]" type="tel"  ng-model="prop.price" ng-init="prop.price=600000">
      </label>

      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">Down Payment (%)</span>
        <input type="tel" name="prop[payment]" ng-model="prop.payment" ng-init="prop.payment=20" ng-click="update(prop)">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">Zipcode</span>
        <input type="tel" name="prop[zip]" ng-model="prop.zip" ng-init="prop.zip=93110">
      </label>

      <a  class="button button-full button-dark" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" href="#/tab/income" ng-click="update(prop)" >NEXT</a>

   </form>
```

I have 2 other views where data is submitted to the prop object and then 2 views where it gets calculated.

Here's my zillow factory:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('zillowFactory', function prop($http){

  return {
    setProperty: function(prop){
      console.log("in the set property call");
      prop = {};
      prop.price = "";
      prop.payment = "";
      prop.zip = "";
      prop.fees = "";
      prop.rental = "";
      prop.totalincome = "";
      prop.householdincome = "";
      prop.maintenance = "";
      prop.utilities = "";
      prop.other = "";
      return prop;
    },
    getProperty: function(prop) {
        prop.montlypayment = {};
        // console.log("This is a price" + " " + prop.price);
         console.log("in the get property call");
        $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetMonthlyPayments.htm?MYAPI KEY HEREe=' + prop.price  +'&down=' + prop.payment +'&zip=' + prop.zip + '&output=json',
        type: 'JSON',
        data: ''
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        prop.montlypayment = response.data;
        debugger
        return prop.monthlypayment;

        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
      });
    }
  }

})
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: At this point I can now get the data to go from the first controller, into the facotry, and make the call. After that, it all seems to get lost or over written and $scope.prop is set to Null.

I've been playing around with this for two days now and so far, I still haven't figured out how to move the data through the controllers. I've been using the Debugger and am at a bit of a loss for what to do next.

Comment: Would need to see what `zillowFactory` does. Does if update `$rootScope.prop`? Generally not a good thing to use rootScope as a data store and better to use a service. Your overall problem isn't very clear. Suggest you create a demo that reproduces it

Comment: user3787971, Do you mean first three screens data to appear in final screens?

Comment: if i understand correctly you want to share data between controllers....As a good design use services to share data between controllers...

Comment: Yes the first three screens are where the data gets entered and then the same data is calculated in an equation on the last two screens. That's why I'm using root scope. Adding the zillow factory now.

Comment: users2967711  can you provide me with an example? I added the zillow factory. I'm just not sure how to set that up. Still figuring out angular:) Thank you.

Comment: Could this be as easy as just calling $scope.$apply() after you call the update method? When you say "call the zillowApi", it's likely that's occurring async/out of the digest. When you do that you may need to apply the scope explicitly.

Comment: Hey Tim, I tried scope.apply but I don't think I was using it correctly. I kept getting an error about the digest cycle and found another stack overflow question saying that scope.apply was to be avoided. Happy to try it but I'm not exactly sure on the syntax.

Comment: If you want to have data between multiple conntrollers, use  service to store that data.

Comment: I've updated the question and made some changes but am still stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little hard to tell what you are trying to do exactly, but there are at least these two problems:

1) You call `zillowFactory.getProp()` a few times without an argument, but getProp() functions by changing the attributes of its argument. So it's probably not doing any harm (other than causing a few useless network requests), but if you're expecting it to do something useful, it's not.

2) In SumCtrl, you assign the values of `expenses30`, `expensesFifty`, and `expensesFive` using values on $scope.prop. But you are setting the values of $scope.prop asynchronously (after the zillow call has been returned) in `zillowFactory.getProperty()`. So those values will not be calculated correctly.

I would just rewrite your zillowFactory to both (a) hold the data, and (b) calculate the values you want to calculate from that data. Something along these lines:

```html
angular.factory('zillowFactory', function($http) {

  var prop = {};
  return {
    /** get the prop. 
     * to update, you can do $scope.prop = zillowFactory.getProp() in your controllers
    */
    getProp() {
      return prop;
    },
    getZillow() {
      $http.get('http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetMonthlyPayments.htm?MYAPI KEY HEREe=' + prop.price  +'&down=' + prop.payment +'&zip=' + prop.zip + '&output=json').then(function() {
        prop.montlypayment = response.data;
      })
    },
    getExpenses30: function(){
       // you might want to check if these values are set and return "null" or something if they are not
       return (prop.monthlypayment.response.monthlyPropertyTaxes * 12) + (prop.monthlypayment.response.monthlyHazardInsurance * 12) + (prop.monthlypayment.response.thirtyYearFixed.monthlyPrincipalAndInterest * 12) + (prop.maintenance * 12)
   + (prop.fees * 12) + (prop.utilities * 12) + (prop.other * 12) + (prop.price/27.5);
    },
    // 
    getOtherStuff: function() {
       etc...
    }
})
```